# If $P(A)=0$ then $A=\emptyset $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $P$ be a probability function. It satisfied [probability axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms). Can we deduce from it that if $P(A)=0$ then $A=\emptyset $ ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, e.g. if $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ then it is a probability measure, but $P(A) = 0$ for any countable $A$. One may even go further and say that $P(C) = 0$ when $C$ is a [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which is known to be uncountable. I would really advise you check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility).

Comment: Of course, no need to use a continuous probability to find examples - you can just define a probability on $\{0,1\}$ with $P(\{0\})=P(\emptyset)=0$ and $P(\{1\})=P(\{0,1\})=1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: that's true, though it seems that OP has recently started learning this topic - and I thought that the Lebesgue measure may give more "natural" and enlightening examples.

Comment: Well, if they were new to the topic of probability, then they might not even know what Lebesgue measurability means - lots of probability classes - possibly even most- do not require measure theory.