# A question about probability (1)

Tags: probability

Given a circle $C$ of radius $a$, a point is selected at random within the circle, what is the probability that the point is the centre of the circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that we're working in a real circle. Then the circle contains uncountably many points and so the probability is $0$, surely.

Comment: Thats what I thought but it seems unlikely. If the probability is $0$ then the event can **never** happen..

Comment: No, probability $0$ doesn't mean that the event can't happen, that's only true in a finite state space. It's a similar problem to "Pick a real number". Any real number has probability $0$ of being chosen but some real number will be chosen.

Comment: @TomLynd Have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility

Comment: That makes sense