# What does Borel's large number theorem really mean?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

According to [this page](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Borel_strong_law_of_large_numbers) in "Encyclopedia in Mathematics", the Borel's large number theorem can be stated as below.

"Consider independent random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots$ which are identically distributed and assume one of two values 0 and 1 with probability of 1/2 each; the expression $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k}$ will then give the number of successful trials in a Bernoulli scheme in which the probability of success is 1/2. Borel [[B]](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Borel_strong_law_of_large_numbers#B) showed that

$ \frac{S_n}{n} \to \frac{1}{2} $

with probability one as $n \to \infty$.
"

### ***Question 1***:

Does the last sentence in the above statement mean (precisely) the sequence $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges "[almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence)" to $\frac{1}{2}$ (with probability 1) as the following?

$P( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{ \frac{S_n}{n} } = \frac{1}{2} ) = 1 $

namely,

$
P(\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \; n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \;
| \frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{1}{2} | \lt \epsilon, \forall n \ge n_0 ) = 1
$

where $P$ denotes the probability.

### ***Question 2***:

On the other hand, the definition of "[almost sure convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence)" doesn't make sense. Because for some event $E$, the notation "$P(E) = 1$" means the event $E$ is certain. So we should be able to drop "$P() = 1$", therefore

$P(E) = 1 \Leftrightarrow E$

which is confusing to me. I can see that, if we had the notation "$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{P(E(n)) = 1}$", then we wouldn't be able to drop the "$P() = 1$" inside the limit, since this would be the definition to an asymptotic probability.

I appreciate any help to get me understand these basic concepts.

EDIT NOTE: I have edited and split the text into 2 questions.

==========================

RE-EDIT: adding question 3.

### ***Question 3***:

If my understanding in question 1 is accurate (see above), why is the following result by Khinchin the stronger one? From the same [page](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Borel_strong_law_of_large_numbers) in "Encyclopedia in Mathematics",

> $\dots$ after which (1922) the stronger result:
>
> $ P( \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}
>        { \frac{ |\frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{1}{2}| }
>               { \sqrt{nloglogn} }
>          = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
>        }
>       ) = 1 $
>
> was proved by A.Ya. Khinchin.

My reasoning is, since both theorems state the limit with probability 1 (almost sure convergence), I could drop the notation "$P()$" and only compare the statement inside the "P()". The Borel's theorem states that, $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ that is the bound of $| \frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{1}{2} |$, as long as $n \ge n_0$ and $n_0$ exists. But the divergent function $f(n) \equiv nloglogn$, in Khinchin's theorem, can be much bigger than the given $\epsilon$ when $n \ge n_0$. So the limit from the above with the divergent function $f(n) \equiv nloglogn$ doesn't seem to be the stronger one at all.

Comment: $P(E)=1$ does not imply $E$ always happens (similarly, $P(E)=0$ does not imply $E$ never happens). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531092/if-px-x-0-for-a-continuous-rv-x-then-isnt-that-it-is-impossible-to-o/1531102) for past discussions.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks so much! That makes sense. I have edited and split the text into 2 questions. Your comment answered question 2. Is the question 1 too obvious and I just didn'r realize it? If so, please do help me understand it.

Comment: For question 1, I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: @angryavian I re-edited text to bring up the question 3. My apologies for keep editting the question but I promise this is the last question added. The question 3 was my original motivation to post the question 1, about which I thought I had mis-conceptions.

Comment: It might be better to write your third question as a new self-contained question.