# Probability of two random real numbers being equal

Tags: probability

Two real numbers $a, b \in [0, k]$.
What is the probability for $a = b$ ?

The probability is uniform, so:

$$ P(a=b) = \lim_{n \to ∞} \frac n {n^2} = \frac 1 n = 0 $$

But $a$ **can** equal $b$ because they are in the same domain.
So why is $P(a=b) = 0$ ?

Comment: Saying $P(E) = 0$ is not the same as saying that the event $E$ is impossible.

Comment: Why is that? (this string is just to fill 15 characters)

Comment: For any $c \in [a, b]$, $a < b$, the probability that a uniformly randomly selected number in $[a, b]$ is $c$ is zero. If this meant that the event that the selected number is $c$ is impossible, then since $c$ is arbitrary...

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility.

Answer (score 1):

The sample space here is the product space $[0,k]\times[0,k]$ with the uniform probability on the rectangle $[0,k]\times [0,k]$, which gives to every (measurable) subset it's area. The event $a=b$ is simply the diagonal of the rectangle, which has area $=$ zero, hence probability $=$ zero.

Comment: Probability is relative frequency after a long time.Does zero probability mean that the event will not repeat? No matter how many times one does the attempt?

Comment: No, it does not mean that the event will never occur. In any physical experiment, it could happen that on your very first choice of a point in the rectangle, you stumble across a point that belongs to the diagonal. Events that have probability zero *can* happen. To prove that an event has probability zero by relative frequency when you are only allowed finitely many experiments is mathematically impossible. You will get a very small relative frequency, though.