# Probability Math Including Zero Probability Events

Tags: probability

Consider two independent events, A and B. We would say the probability of A **and** B occurring is:

```
P(A ∩ B) = P(A) * P(B)
```

However, what if A is considered a [zero probability event](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41107/305713)? Not an *impossibility*, but a *zero probability event*? (**Not** the empty set)

If this is the case, **what can we say about the relationship between P(A) and P(A ∩ B)?**

Does P(A) = P(A ∩ B), because P(A) = 0? Or, is P(A ∩ B) < P(A)?

B is **not** a zero probability event:

```
P(B) ∈ (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\cap B \subset A$, we have $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A) = 0$. The relationship $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, but it doesn't give anything useful about $B$. Independence with almost-never-occurring events isn't a very useful concept, since the first equation in your post holds trivially. (If you state independence terms of conditional probabilities, note that $P(B\vert A)$ is't defined for $P(A) = 0$).

Comment: So, `P(A∩B)≤P(A)`? But, not `P(A∩B)=P(A)`?

Comment: Well, $P(A) = 0$.