# Understanding the probability of a point, it's zero but point is observable.

Tags: probability

Okay so this might be a basic question/stupid question, but I cannot find an answer for it.

So let's say we have a continuous random variable that returns a value in 0, 1. I know that the probability to observe any single given point in this interval is zero (one point over infinite). How come I can observe this point that has no probability to be observed ?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility

Comment: The short answer is "that's just the way probability works".  As Von Neumann once said, "in mathematics, you don't understand things, you just get used to them".

Comment: You seem to be conflating "probability $0$" with "impossible".