# If two points are chosen at random on the circumference of the circle, find the probability that the selected points form the diameter of the circle.

Tags: geometric-probability

***Question:***
If two points are chosen at random on the circumference of the circle, find the probability that the selected points form the diameter of the circle.

---

***My thoughts:***
For the $2$ points to be the diameter of the circle, they must be diametrically opposite of each other. If the first point says $A$ is selected, then the number of possible choices for the second point let say $B$ will be only $1$.

When one point is chosen from the uncountable infinite points on a circle there are only one of those infinite points that will form a diameter with the first point.

So the probability is given by, $$P(E) = \dfrac{1}{\infty} \equiv 0$$

So the probability must be $0$.

---

How is it possible that the probability of the event is $0$ even if the event is possible? The answer given in my textbook is also $0$ but I'm not quite sure about this. This question is confusing. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This is a general property of continuous distributions....the probability of any particular outcome is $0$.  No need for such a complicated example...just consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  The probability of getting $\frac 12$ (or any other specified value) is $0$.

Comment: Probability zero is not the same as impossibility.

Comment: In the same way, a probability of 1 does not mean a guaranteed event. Instead, we talk about *almost sure* or *almost impossible* events.

Comment: Would [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility) answer your question canonically? Note that your attempt is correct.

Comment: This is because of the same reason why the probability of hitting the bullseye with the dart is zero even if that's possible.

Comment: Dude. Don't delete your account. Just take a break from this site. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points on a circle are an absolutely continuous probability distribution, which means that we are picking  two points out of an uncountably infinite amount of points. The answer to this question is indeed $0$. Even though this may seem unintuitive, just because the probability of an event is $0$ does not mean that it is an impossible event. This is especially true for continuous distributions. Also, even if we have a countably infinite amount of possibilites, the probability will still be $0$. This means that the probability of picking a certain random natural number out of all the natural numbers is $0$, even though it is not impossible.